# SBPLLatticePlannerStats.h file not found

Tags: ros, sbpl-lattice-planner, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the file SBPLLatticePlannerStats.h is missing from the sbpl_lattice_planner package available on https://kforge.ros.org/navigation/experimental/file/7ad215f4368f/sbpl_lattice_planner/include/sbpl_lattice_planner.

```
$ rosmake sbpl_lattice_planner on ubuntu 11.04 with ros electric gives following error:

                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_core [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_core [PASS] [ 0.53 seconds ]                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sbpl_lattice_planner [ make ]                          
[ rosmake ] All 17 linesbpl_lattice_planner: 0.7 ... [ 1 Active 56/57 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package sbpl_lattice_planner
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- checking for module 'sbpl'
  --   package 'sbpl' not found
  CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
    A required package was not found
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
    CMakeLists.txt:15 (pkg_check_modules)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package sbpl_lattice_planner written to:plete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/auto/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120704-161258/sbpl_lattice_planner/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sbpl_lattice_planner [FAIL] [ 0.81 seconds ]           
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package sbpl_lattice_planner. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 57 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/auto/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120704-161258              
[ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not detect the following system dependencies as installed: sbpl Consider using --rosdep-install option or `rosdep install sbpl_lattice_planner
```

how to solve?

thankyou

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37897/sbpllatticeplannerstats.h-file-not-found/) by [gautam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2763/gautam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-07-09**:
@gautam: can you paste the exact error that you receive regarding sbpllatticeplannerstats.h? I can build the stack just fine.

**Comment by [gautam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2763/gautam/) on 2012-07-10**:
@piyush: the code sbpl_lattice_planner.cpp requires sbpllatticeplannerstats.h header file which is not present in the include directory of the package. kindly tell me if you have this file in your include folder. If you have it then where did you get the source from?  Because it is absent in the

**Comment by [gautam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2763/gautam/) on 2012-07-10**:
source repository (link mentioned above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are misinterpreting the error. The error states that the [sbpl](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sbpl) package was not found. You need to install the [motion_planners](http://www.ros.org/wiki/motion_planners) stack before you can build the sbpl_lattice_planner package.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1